Why did Tao include the reflexive axiom for equality here? (Analysis I)
In Analysis I, Tao lists several axioms which equality, defined upon a class of objects $T$, must satisfy. The reflexive axiom he gives is

Given any object $x$, we have $x=x$.

However, from Wikipedia here, equality between 2 expressions asserts "that the expressions represent the same mathematical object". This makes the reflexive axiom seem superfluous- as if we say that object $A$ and object $B$ from a class of objects $T$ are the same iff $A=B$, then the reflexive axiom isn't needed as for any object $A$, $A$ is the same as itself; so by the forward direction of the implication just expounded, $A=A$.
So why do we include the reflexive axiom here, and how does the statement from Wikipedia which says being equal is equivalent to being the same object fit in the context of axioms for equality?

Your Wikipedia quote is an intuitive notion, telling you one way to think about the $=$ symbol, telling you what the symbol is intended to represent. But it is not an axiom. There is not really any mathematical rigor behind it.
If you scroll down the Wikipedia page to the section "Basic properties", you will see reflexivity listed there too, just as it is in Tao's book. Because it should be.

even if the Wikipedia quote is just presented an intuitive notion, isn't it still the case that its statement can be rigorous- as Tao gives axioms in terms of 'objects', which he doesn't define; e.g. he gives as an axiom that sets are objects. If we have a notion of objects, then isn't it rigorous to say that if $A=B$, $A$ and $B$ are the same object?

It can be made rigorous using the reflexivity axiom.

@NaimFavier however, the reflexive axiom isn't equivalent to it- it says if 2 things are the same object, then they are equal; but we want to say also the converse, that equality between 2 things implies they are the same object. How would you formalize the statement from Wikipedia using the reflexivity axiom?

No, it says that anything is equal to itself. "Equal" and "same" are synonyms.

@NaimFavier ok thanks, but how do you make rigoroususing reflexivity that equality between 2 things implies they are the same object? remarking upon the verbal import of "equal" and "same" being identical isn't rigorous, if that was the purpose of  your  remark to that effect.

...using the reflexivity axiom, $\forall x. x = x$. I feel like we're running in circles here. "Rigorous" means "expressed in a formal system of reasoning".

@naimFavier how does $\forall x, x=x$ rigorize that if 2 things are equal, they are the same object? it seems to me that the reflexivity axiom is more the converse of this- that the same objects are equal

Are you looking for the substitution property?

Defining "equals" sounds tricky -- like you're trying to define what "is" is.  Instead, it is helpful to think about what a relation is for a set.  For example, consider the set $\{1,2,3,4\}$ and this relation on it:  $\{(1,2),(2,3),(3,1),(4,4)\}$.  If we use the symbol "$\sim$" for this relation, we write $1 \sim 2$, $4 \sim 4$, etc.:  i.e., $a \sim b$ for every ordered pair $(a,b)$ in the relation.  Which of the "big three" properties of relations (i.e., reflexive, symmetric, and transitive) does the relation "$\sim$" have?
How about the relation $\{(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,3),(2,4),(3,4)\}$?  Which of the big three properties does it have, and what symbol would you use for it?  How about the relation $\{(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4)\}$?
As you answer questions like this, you'll start to sound like Tao:  such-and-so relation has such-and-so property or satisfies such-and-so axiom.
